# Comparing value from a cell in one datagridview to another

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

first of all, following is my codes:

```vb
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    'Establish connection with sql server. Fill the data in data grid view (dgvData)

    For i As Integer = 2 To dgvData.Columns.Count() - 1

        dgvSettings.Rows.Add(dgvData.Columns(i).HeaderText, 0, 100, "High")

    Next

End Sub

Public Sub comparevalues()

    For z As Integer = 2 To dgvData.ColumnCount - 1

        If dgvData.Rows(0).Cells(z).Value.ToString() > dgvSettings.Rows(z - 2).Cells(2).Value.ToString() Then

            MsgBox("Value Exceed Maximum Limit")

            dgvAlert.Rows.Add(False, dgvData.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value.ToString(), dgvData.Columns(z).HeaderText.ToString(), dgvData.Rows(0).Cells(z).Value.ToString(), "Unacknowledged", dgvSettings.Rows(z - 2).Cells(3).Value.ToString())

        ElseIf dgvData.Rows(0).Cells(z).Value.ToString() < dgvSettings.Rows(z - 2).Cells(1).Value.ToString() Then

            MsgBox("Value Below Minimum Limit")

            dgvAlert.Rows.Add(False, dgvData.Rows(0).Cells(1).Value.ToString(), dgvData.Columns(z).HeaderText.ToString(), dgvData.Rows(0).Cells(z).Value.ToString(), "Unacknowledged", dgvSettings.Rows(z - 2).Cells(3).Value.ToString())

        Else
            'in range, do nothing
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

[this is dgvdata table, it is linked to my sql server db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzezF.png)

[this is dgvalert table, any values from latest row in dgvdata that meets the condition as in comparevalues() will be tabulated here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FmYEe.png)

[this is dgvsettings table, the limit conditions are all set in here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iXsU.png)

so here is what i'm trying to do, although some of you might be able to interpret from the code given above. After filling up the dgvData with my sql data table, i'd like to compare the values in each columns of the latest row as according to the condition set in the comparevalues() sub. ie. if a value in, lets say column pH, exceeds the value limit set in the dgvSettings, then it will then added into the dgvAlert table.

but the problem is, when i run the code, those within the range set in the dgvSettings are still added into the dgvAlert. and most of them are taken as exceeded the limit when it should be still in the range limit. i've been cracking my head since the past few days trying to get it right. Your help is much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Why is your indenting all over the place?  Making code harder to read is not the best way to get people to help you with it.  Given that VS can maintain proper code formatting for you, there's really no excuse for not posting properly formatted code.

Comment: @jmcilhinney My apology for that. I've fixed it now. Thank you.

Comment: why are you comparing strings with <  and > ?

Comment: @preciousbetine i must've stated it wrongly. What I meant was to check whether that one cell is < or > than the other cell..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing it wrong.

You have to convert those strings to actual numbers first if you want to compare them.

```
Public Sub comparevalues()
For z= 2 To dgvData.ColumnCount - 1
    Dim Cell1 as Double = CDbl(dgvData(z,0).Value.ToString)
    Dim Cell2 as Double = CDbl(dgvSettings(2,z-2).Value.ToString)
    Dim Cell3 as Double = CDbl(dgvSettings(1,z-2).Value.ToString)

    If Cell1  > Cell2 Then
        MsgBox("Value Exceed Maximum Limit")
        dgvAlert.Rows.Add(False, dgvData(1,0).Value.ToString, dgvData.Columns(z).HeaderText.ToString(), dgvData(z,0).Value.ToString, "Unacknowledged", dgvSettings(3,z-2).Value.ToString)
    ElseIf Cell1  < Cell3 Then
        MsgBox("Value Below Minimum Limit")
        dgvAlert.Rows.Add(False, dgvData(1,0).Value.ToString, dgvData.Columns(z).HeaderText.ToString(), dgvData(z,0).Value.ToString, "Unacknowledged", dgvSettings(3,z-2).Value.ToString)
    Else
        'in range, do nothing
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: It appears that many of the columns include decimal points so Integer is not going to work.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! It works like a charm. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following to see why comparing strings with < and > does not work for your case.

```
Private Sub Form3_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim x As String = "7".ToString
        Dim y As String = "10".ToString
        If x > y Then
            MessageBox.Show("7 is greater than 10")
        ElseIf x < y Then
            MessageBox.Show("10 is greater than 7")
        End If
End Sub
```

Get rid of the .ToString